# Duplicate SPN's - ADFS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, adfs, single-sign-on, entra-id, spn

Trying to setup ADFS with AD Connect. I get an error message when trying to add the ADFS service account. The error states that there is already an existing service account in the directory with the ADFS service Service Principal Name (SPN).

I ran `setspn -x`found 0 groups of duplicate SPNs.

What else can cause this error message?

Running Server 2012R2

Answer (score 0):

You could check the existing ADFS service SPN by `setspn -q host/<adfs farm name>`, For example `setspn -q host/fs.contoso.com`

Comment: Is my reply helpful?